# Convert string to string template from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the best way to use ES2015 string templates from another file?

template.html

```
<div>
    <span>Hello, my name is ${name}.</span>
    <span>I'm a ${title}.</span>
</div>
```

main.js

```
let template = '';
let name = "Adam Curl"
let title = "Coder"
$.get("template.html", function(response) {
     template = response;
});
console.log(template);
```

Wishing to output...

```
<div>
    <span>Hello, my name is Adam Curl.</span>
    <span>I'm a Coder.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `console.log(template);` may not be defined when `$.get()` is called. `$.get()` callback returns results asynchronously.

Comment: See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3853934)